# How to ping an address from specific interface by salt?

Tags: networking, salt-stack

I know we can ping an address using command below([official doc](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.network.html)):

```
salt '*' network.ping archlinux.org
```

but how to specify the interface?
I know it should be possible because we can do it in terminal or command prompt:

windows:

```
ping  -4 192.168.0.1 -s 1
```

Ubuntu:

```
ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8
```

so we can use `salt '*' cmd.run "<command to execute>"`  but is there a better way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the code reveals that this feature hasn't yet been added to the `network.ping` function.  It doesn't look like it would be hard to add.

Here's the function definition:  https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/d7f242b9ca77dee0e80abb38d45493f1db609a65/salt/modules/network.py#L63

Feel free to open an issue here:  https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/new

Or open a pull request if you'd like to add that functionality yourself.